# How to display a user profile property in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3, asp.net-authentication

In my `ASP.NET Core 1.1.1` app with `Identity 3.0`, I've extended the default `ApplicationUser` class as follows. In my following `Index` view I'm displaying the `userName` on top bar by using `@User.Identity.Name`. **Question**: How can I display the user's full name instead using `UserFullName` property below?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string UserName { get; set; } 
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(45)")]
    public string UserFullName { get; set; } 
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(15)")]
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
  Hello @User.Identity.Name
  ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

The `ASPNETUsers` table is already populated with `UserName` and `UserFullName` columns and have their values i.e. `JSmith, John Smith`, `BDoe, Bob Doe`, etc. So the question is if `JSmith` is logged in user, we can display his user Hello JSmith as `@User.Identity.Name`. But how do I display `John Smith`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a calculated field like this.

```
public string FullName() { return String.Format("{0} {1}",FirstName,LastName); }
```

Comment: Probably I was not that clear in the post. I've now added an UPDATE for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The User in the page is not an ApplicationUser but an IPrinicipal.  You need to get the ApplicationUser like this.

```
 ApplicationUserManager manager= 
     HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

 var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

 // use currentUser.UserFullName
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates/